# Flutter video_player can not show the video

Tags: flutter, video, dart, android-video-player

I use video_player 0.10.4+1 but when i run the application my video can not play it's transparent. Like this. [here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OgFb.jpg) And This is my code for showing the video.

```
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
 VideoPlayerController _controller;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(
      'assets/vi1.mp4')
    ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});
  });
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Video Demo',
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: _controller.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : Container(),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _controller.value.isPlaying
              ? _controller.pause()
              : _controller.play();
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
        _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

@override
void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
 _controller.dispose();
}
}
```

This is how i import the above file.

```
class ActivityClip extends StatefulWidget {
ActivityClip({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_ActivityState createState() => _ActivityState();
}

class _ActivityState extends State<ActivityClip> {
final List<String> numbers = [
'Soft Music',
'Meditation',
'Pray',
'Breathing',
'Relex'
 ];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 350),
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: numbers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              width: 200,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.brown,
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    numbers[index].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                  )),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _showMaterialDialog();
                 //activityVideo(context);
                },
              ));
        }));  
       }

_showMaterialDialog() {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
          content: Container(
    height: 400,
     width: 300,
          child: VideoApp()),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Close me!'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        ));
       }


     }
```

I'm not sure that this code is wrong or from my device because there is on error at all.
Thank you for all suggestion.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with code. did you make sure that you currently added video in assets and can you add more code where you use alertDialog variable because i tested code by wrapping AlertDialog with ShowDialog without assigning to any variable.

Comment: Can i use the tuterial how to use ShowDialog like this link? https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-show-dialog/ and for content I called VideoApp() class.

Comment: Yes that's the right way.

Comment: Sorry sir, I still have the same problem that video doesn't show although i change to wrapping AlertDialog with ShowDialog.

Comment: can you check it os working for network video or not. use following link for video because package provide video link is not working. http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Comment: i tried your link, still have the same problem. I already edit my code that i use  ShowDialog. You can check my code again in above.

Comment: i think there is problem is that you did not give currently add video in assets folder. can you check it again that video is at correct place and also add pubspec.yaml file code where you add video. Moreover, also try flutter clean and give full restart because i check your code is working fine.

Comment: I put the video in assets->vi1.mp4 and in pubspec.yaml in add - assets/vi1.mp4. Are you run my code? On your device, is the video show?

Comment: Yes I tried and working fine. Can you add pubspec.yaml file here. And did you try flutter clean and then run full restart?

Comment: After i use flutter clean. it works!!. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding any package or assets it is always advisable to do flutter clean and flutter run.

Comment: You are right, i had same issue, but after run flutter clean, it started to work.